# Layout Zooming with widget

Tags: android

I'm trying to zoom a layout wit an image background and widgets like textview. I already implemented the pinch zooming by searching and following some tutorials. But the problem is it is not smooth when zooming the layout (Flickering).

So is there anyone have a solution regards this issue? Or have a different approach how to zoom a layout smoothly?

Any thoughts will be highly appreciated.

Here is my codes:

```
public class ZoomActivity extends Activity {

    View mainView = null;
    PointF start = new PointF();
    PointF mid = new PointF();
    float oldDist = 1f;
    PointF oldDistPoint = new PointF();

    public static String TAG = "ZOOM";

    static final int NONE = 0;
    static final int DRAG = 1;
    static final int ZOOM = 2;
    int mode = NONE;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.landingpage);
        mainView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear);

        mainView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                Log.d(TAG, "mode=DRAG");
                switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                    Log.d(TAG, "mode=DRAG");
                    mode = DRAG;

                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                    oldDist = spacing(event);
                    oldDistPoint = spacingPoint(event);
                    Log.d(TAG, "oldDist=" + oldDist);
                    if (oldDist > 10f) {
                        midPoint(mid, event);
                        mode = ZOOM;
                        Log.d(TAG, "mode=ZOOM");
                    }
                    System.out.println("current time :"
                            + System.currentTimeMillis());
                    break;// return !gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                    Log.d(TAG, "mode=NONE");
                    mode = NONE;
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    if (mode == DRAG) {

                    } else if (mode == ZOOM) {
                        PointF newDist = spacingPoint(event);
                        float newD = spacing(event);
                        Log.e(TAG, "newDist=" + newDist);
                        float[] old = new float[9];
                        float[] newm = new float[9];
                        Log.e(TAG, "x=" + old[0] + ":&:" + old[2]);
                        Log.e(TAG, "y=" + old[4] + ":&:" + old[5]);
                        float scale = newD / oldDist;
                        float scalex = newDist.x / oldDistPoint.x;
                        float scaley = newDist.y / oldDistPoint.y;
                        zoom(scale, scale, start);
                    }
                    break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * zooming is done from here
     */
    public void zoom(Float scaleX, Float scaleY, PointF pivot) {
        mainView.setPivotX(pivot.x);
        mainView.setPivotY(pivot.y);
        mainView.setScaleX(scaleX);
        mainView.setScaleY(scaleY);
    }

    /**
     * space between the first two fingers
     */
    private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
        // ...
        float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
        return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    }

    private PointF spacingPoint(MotionEvent event) {
        PointF f = new PointF();
        f.x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
        f.y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
        return f;
    }

    /**
     * the mid point of the first two fingers
     */
    private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
        // ...
        float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
        point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this zoomview -> https://code.google.com/p/android-zoom-view/

They use matrix and canvas to scale your view. To use it is very simple you can copy the java file from the repository to your project then you can  add it to your xml view like this

```
<yourpackagename.ZoomvView>
     //place your view that want to be zoomed here
</yourpackagename.ZoomvView>
```

Comment: Can you give a tutorial how to use this jar?

Comment: just download the java file from the repository here https://code.google.com/p/android-zoom-view/source/browse/src/pl/polidea/view/ZoomView.java then copy it to your project and how to use is like I said in my answer above :)

Comment: I thinks it need to match or fill parent all the size of the widget. Wrap Content is not allow

Comment: ah yes I'm sorry I forgot to mention that,have you successfully implement this zoomview?if not I can give you a XML example :)

Comment: the problem is I have a lot of textview that need to be wrap content

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for asking a question but if you encountered this error
"  Custom view ZoomView is not using the 2- or 3-argument View constructors; XML attributes will not work "

just add these in the java class ZoomView

public ZoomView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet)

{
    super(context, attributeSet);

```
//TODO:
```

}

Comment: Please do not put new questions or requests for clarification in an answer. It is better to put new questions as a new question (following the SO rules) and other comments regarding this specific question as comments to the question.